# How to make a squirm effect by react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Effects similar to this figure

Comment: Squirm effect of this indicator is very special, I can not use the react-native to implement it, but looking forward to your reply

Comment: maybe this is something you are looking for? https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Comment: @MrMuetze I read its source code, but it's not what I need animation

Comment: Have you tried to implement this animation yourself by hand? I don't have experience with react, but it seems a simple enough animation. Also it will be much easier to help you with code problems than to provide you with entire solution.

Comment: Hah I did this too, I did the thing in javascript but its really simple you just need to track the % shift of the upper slider and use it to translate the value of the dots. 

Really give it a try.